# Alert which checkbox[x] of array was clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code onclick for each checkbox function is:

```
function testc() {
   var values1 = new Array();
   jQuery.each(jQuery("input.id1"), function() {
     values1.push(jQuery(this).attr("name"));
   });
   var values2 = new Array();
   jQuery.each(jQuery("input.id76"), function() {
     values2.push(jQuery(this).attr("name")); 
   });
   //build arrays

   var attname = "[name='"+values1[this]+"']"; //there should also be indexof clicked checkbox

   jQuery("input:[type=checkbox]"+attname).attr("checked", true);

   alert(values1.findIndex(jQuery(this).attr("name")));
}
```

What's wrong? :/ I think the problem is how I'm getting indexes.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do onclick?  some html might be nice to see?

Comment: Why do you store the names in arrays to begin with?

Comment: Because of stupid server-side part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring issues of *why* you're setting up the arrays like that and what you're trying to do, I think the problem with the alert is that there isn't a `findIndex()` array method. Did you mean [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
alert(values1.indexOf(jQuery(this).attr("name")))
```